# how can I get good binary image using Otsu method for this image?

Tags: image, matlab

here is my image
[a.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIDSh.jpg)

for binarization I try this code.

```
im=rgb2gray(I);
maxp=uint16(max(max(im)));
minp=uint16(min(min(im)));
bw=im2bw(im,(double(minp+maxp))/(1.42*255));  
bw=~bw; 
imm=bw;
```

but I need binarization by otsu.how can I get good binary output  using otsu method?
plz help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB has its own implementation of [Otsu thresholding](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/multithresh.html) called `multithresh`. In your case the code to obtain the segmented image should be something like this:

```
im=rgb2gray(I); % convert image to grayscale
thresh = multithresh(im); % find one threshold (using Otsu method)

segmented_im = imquantize(im, thresh); % segment image
imagesc(segmented_im); % show segmented image
```

I haven't tested it so I don't know how well it would perform on your image.

**EDIT:**

I tested it, and it doesn't work as expected. One of the problems is that Otsu's method works well when there is a clear bimodal distribution of the pixel intensities. This bimodality is lacking in your image. A call to `imhist(im)` after the grayscale conversion leads to this (comments added by me):

[image]

As you can see, the distribution is almost trimodal, and the threshold selected by `multithresh` is the first one, while you want the second one. The first workaround that comes to my mind (especially if all the images in your dataset are similar to the one you posted, i.e. have a similar intensity distribution) is to make `multithresh` output two thresholds, and then selecting the last (highest) one:

```
thresholds = multithresh(im, 2);
thresh = thresholds(end);
```

Then proceed with the segmentation of the image as stated above. This second method leads to this segmentation:

[image]

**EDIT 2 (putting it all together):**

Indeed the output `segmented_im` is not a binary image, but a label image. It's easy enough to convert it to a binary image. I will include directly all the code in this next snippet:

```
im=rgb2gray(I); % convert image to grayscale
thresholds = multithresh(im, 2); % find two thresholds using Otsu
thresh = thresholds(end); % select larger one

segmented_im = imquantize(im, thresh); % segment image

segmented_im(segmented_im == 1) = 0; % make background black (0)
segmented_im(segmented_im == 2) = 255; % make foreground white (255)

binary_im = im2bw(segmented_im); % make binary (logical) image

imshow(binary_im); % show binary image
```

`binary_im` il a logical matrix with false (0) for background, and true (1) for foreground. `segmented_im` is a double matrix with 0 for background and 255 for foreground. I hope this serves your purposes!

Comment: I edited the answer. The problem may lie in the non-bimodal distribution of the pixel intensities, that is needed for the standard single threshold Otsu method to work well.

Comment: Sir is this a binary image? Using Otsu method where is the white forground and black background?

Comment: Sir how can I get  white foreground and black background binary image from your output image? plz help.

Comment: @EifaTasnim I added the "binarization" code, hopefully this is what you are looking for. In case, please consider accepting the answer.